# Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, dreamhost

I'm trying to access a remote database from Dreamhost with my Ruby on Rails app with no luck locally or remotely.

I keep getting this error when I try to `rake db:migrate`:

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'108-233-86-201.lightspeed.sntcca.sbcglobal.net' (using password: YES)
```

I have checked that:

- Passwords and usernames are correct
- My IP Address from my local server is whitelisted for remote access
- My IP Address from Heroku + Proximo is whitelisted for remote access

This is what my **database.yml** looks like when I'm testing:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: "yoshirtdb"
  pool: 5
  username: "USERNAME"
  password: "XXXXXX"
  host: "phpadmin.domain.com"
  port: 3306

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: "mysql_production"
  pool: 5
  host: "localhost"
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: "yoshirtdb"
  pool: 5
  username: "root"
  password: "root"
  host: "localhost"
  port: 8889
  socket: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Connecting to my local db works.  So I have them saved under **production** right now.  Please ignore that.  Also, I have changed the usernames/password and domains for security purposes.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Additionally, when I just run `rake db:create` the only messaging that I get is:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"yoshirtdb", "username"=>"USERNAME", "password"="XXXXXX">"", "host"=>"phpadmin.domain.com"}
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"mysql_production", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>3306}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

Comment: Problem must be one of those you say you checked. Basically either pass is wrong or some access rights are wrong.

Comment: Turns out the IP I whitelisted was not working.  I whitelisted  `%.amazonaws.com` instead and it worked!